# Creating a Button With C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, button

I'm working on designing a game in C++ and am currently working on my main menu which includes three buttons for three difficulty levels. The problem is, I don't actually know how to create a button in C++. I came across a couple of YouTube tutorials on how to do this, but both guys doing the videos were just inserting this piece of code into an existing program and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to work with my code.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    system("color e0");
    cout << "Can You Catch Sonic?" << endl;
    cout << "Can you find which block Sonic is hiding under? Keep your eyes peeled for that speedy hedgehog and try to find him after the blocks stop moving" << endl;
    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Easy"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
        10, 10, 80, 25, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the console pops up with the correct background color and messages, but there is no button. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure it has something to do with all those NULLs, but not sure what to replace them with.

This is what the code from the YouTube video was, but like I said, it was in the middle of a program that had already been created:

```
CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Hello"), 
   WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
   10, 10, 80, 25,
   hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
```

Any ideas? I'm really new to this so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you pop up an window in a console app? There's no message loop in console app, so the window will not show.

Comment: Find a tutorial; there's no simpele answer.

Comment: This is what I was instructed to use (Visual Studio Console Application). @MSalters, do you happen to know of any good tutorials? Like I mentioned, I've found a few, but they're all the same (just adding this snippet into already working code).

Comment: @BethTanner I believe you should be looking at Win32 programming tutorials.

Comment: If this is school work then you may have to use what you are told, but for a C++ hobby game project you should use something like SDL, or some similar game development framework/library (also Qt would not be too bad choice for some type of games).

Comment: The root problem with the code: You are creating a `WS_CHILD` window without a parent window. This cannot ever work. For a good Windows API programming tutorial check out [theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/). It introduces all major concepts, and doesn't require any working code. It literally starts out with a blank text file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create a message loop and show the button before the loop.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MSG msg;
    //if you add WS_CHILD flag,CreateWindow will fail because there is no parent window.
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Easy"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP,
        10, 10, 80, 25, NULL, NULL, NULL,  NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Gotta play around with the positioning, but this worked :-)

Comment: One more thing, I need to create two more buttons, would I just need to change the variable name to like HWND hWnd1 and create another button?

Comment: @BethTanner,You got it.Don't forget to change the position.